# Angular localization problems with number and date format

Tags: angularjs, localization

I am trying to format a date based on localisation and have the locale files setup correct so when using date format of `shortDate` I get the difference between UK and US format.

However we need the date to show the full year 2016 and not 16.

If I code it as `dd MM yyyy` then that gives me the correct UK format but when toggling to US mode the filter keeps it in that `dd MM yyyy` format.

How can I enable the date to be of type day month year for UK and month day year for US etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```
// US English uses month-day-year order
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US'));
// → "12/19/2012"

// British English uses day-month-year order
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
// → "20/12/2012"
```

Note this is not IE friendly like most of html5 and ES6 :v.

other way is to use http://momentjs.com/